# not able to execute $http method in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I m trying to get the data from web-api. While running on a single html page i am getting the response back with the data but if this script is written separately(out side the html page) i am not able to fetch the data.

this is the first case where data is received successfully.

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
<button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="login()">Get Data</button>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>{{post}}</td>
            <td>{{post.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{post.Price}}</td>
            <td>{{post.Category}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"</script>
<script>    
     var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

     app.controller("PostsCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('http://localhost:35456/api/customer/Dipti123/dipti').
     success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.posts = data;
          alert("recived data");
          //alert(data.data.ID);
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // log error
          alert("error");
      });
});
</script>
```

this is the other case where i m getting error.

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module("angularApp");

app.controller("loginController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.login = function () {
        $http.get('http://localhost:35456/api/customer/Dipti123/dipti').
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = data;
            alert("recived data");
            //alert(data.data.ID);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log error
            alert("error");
        });
    };        
});
```

home.html

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px; position: relative; color:darkorange">
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>{{post}}</td>
            <td>{{post.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{post.Price}}</td>
            <td>{{post.Category}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="angularApp">
<head>
<title>Ebank</title>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/routing.js"></script>
<script src="lib/Controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#333">
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

routing.js

```
(function () {

var app = angular.module("angularApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider            
        .when("/login", {
            templateUrl: "/views/login.html",
            controller: "Controller"
        })
        .when("/info", {
            templateUrl: "/views/info.html",
            controller: "infoController"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/home" });
});

}());
```

can you tell about the mistake done here?
[image]

Comment: you've redirected home.html with `HomeController`. But in controller.js have `loginController`

Comment: I have chanded that part but then to it is not related to error 405. @SankarRaj

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason your not getting the data in your html
See this controller.js below

1. the **$scope.posts** line is commented.
2. The **$scope.login** is a declared as **function** which is not called.

   ```
   app.controller("loginController", function ($scope, $http) {
      /***************************************************/
          $scope.login();
      /***************************************************/
       $scope.login = function () {
           $http.get('http://localhost:35456/api/customer/Dipti123/dipti').
               success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               /***************************************************/
               $scope.posts = data;
               /***************************************************/
               alert("recived data");
               //alert(data.data.ID);
           }).
           error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               // log error
               alert("error");
           });
       };        
   });
   ```

### Update 1:

In the controller you are using **$scope.posts** but in the HTML you are using **post** change it to **posts** as below HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="login()">Get Data</button>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>{{posts}}</td>
            <td>{{posts.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{posts.Price}}</td>
            <td>{{posts.Category}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: but i m getting the alert as error not alert as received data @Aravind

Comment: check your console with **F12** what are the errors ?

Comment: @abhishek i have updated my answer too. Check it and also tell me are you getting the json? if so print in the console. and share the screenshot of console,

Comment: I m getting error 405 which is not related to "posts" after the data is received then i will get that error of post @Aravind

Comment: @abhishek **35456** is the port in which you have the api but in ur screenshot see the port number.

Comment: i m running my angular project on visual studio so the port no will be different for anuglar project and 35456 is the port of web-api project

Comment: tell me your available time